# Mentioning faculty in SOP while already mentioning them elsewhere in application

Tags: phd, statement-of-purpose

Should I explicitly mention faculty in my SOP for a PhD program when there are prompts in other parts of the application where I already specifically chose faculty of interest? Would this be considered redundant?

Answer (score 1):

Use judgement. Not all redundancy is bad. If your goals are tied to one or the other of those professors then it might be worth it.

But I also suggest you stay flexible in choosing a research direction until you are admitted. Insisting on a specific path may not be the best plan, especially if that path is very competitive. In some places there is plenty of time to choose. The US is like that. Places where a PI hires you isn't but it doesn't seem like you are in that situation.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a specific path? I am applying to a Electrical Engineering PhD program at a top university in the US. This department has a branch in photonics, and I could basically work with any of the 7-8 faculty listed on the website. I can't highlight one particular professor and a specific research direction. Just putting them all once again in the sop text doesn't seem like a good idea either.

Comment: Mentioning the branch/specialty is fine, but you don't need to mention the names again. Just don't say that you insist on a very specific research problem with a very specific individual.  That is counterproductive. If you say "photonics" they already know who would be appropriate.

Comment: Ok, thank you, anyway I don't have any specific project in mind, so I'll just talk about photonics in general.

Comment: If you don't mind, I have a follow-up unrelated to the topic: should I mention the research that I've just started (no tangible results yet) doing after describing past experience?

Comment: Only in the SoP if it relates directly to your goals for study. Otherwise, put it in a "work in progress" section of the CV. Maybe both, but at least the latter. The SoP is about goals and plans, not past work or accomplishments.